# Using counter from for loop as condition

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, optimization

I am creating a program in C++ that takes a pdf and converts it into a epub. I am having trouble with my function that reads in the chapters and creates different files for each chapter. The input file will look something like this:

> Chapter 1
>
> > blah blah blah ..... blah
>
> Chapter 2
>
> > blah blah blah ..... blah

I am trying to use the for loop to check the string for the beginning of a chapter and if it is, then create a xhtml file with the name of 'chapter#.xhtml' in the correct directory. The problem I am having is checking for the text and creating the respective file.

```
for(int i=1;i<chapters;i++){
  char j = i;
  string chap = "book/OEBPS/chapters/chapter";
  chap.append(1,j).append(".xhtml");
  if(line == "Chapter "+j){
    out << "</div>\n</body>\n</html>";
    out.close();
    out.open(chap.c_str());
    break;
  }
}
```

Essentially I am trying to create a counter that either is a string or can be added to a string to use in the if statement conditional and the out.open parameter. 
Below is the whole function in case that helps.

```
void readChapters(ofstream& out,int chapters){
  string line,file;
  char letter;
  ifstream in;
  cout << "Enter input file\n";
  cin >> file;
  in.open(file.c_str());
  out.open("junk");
  getline(in,line);
  while(in) {
    for(int i=1;i<chapters;i++){
      char j = i;
      string chap = "book/OEBPS/chapters/chapter";
      chap.append(1,j).append(".xhtml");
      if(line == "Chapter "+j){
        out << "</div>\n</body>\n</html>";
        out.close();
        out.open(chap.c_str());
        break;
      }
    }
    getline(in,line);
    if(line == "\n")
      getline(in,line);
    out << line <<  "\n</p>\n<p>\n";
  }
  out << "</div>\n</body>\n</html>";
  out.close();
  remove("junk");
}
```

Comment: Indexing in c++ usually starts at zero. You probably want to change your for loop conditions like follows: `for(int i=0;i<chapters;i++)`.

Comment: I started at 1 since I was trying to use it to mark the chapters, which would start at chapter 1 @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: This also looks extremly suspicios: `if(line == "Chapter "+j)`, it probably should be something like `if(line == string("Chapter ")+std::to_string(i)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lines does not perform what you would like:

```
char j = i;
```

At most, utter orrible:

```
char j = '0' + i;
```

but I advice you to use ostringstream:

```
std::ostringstream ostr;
ostr << "Chapter " << i;
std::string chap = ostr.str();
```

NOTE:

Not:

```
for(int i=1;i<chapters;i++)
```

But:

```
for(int i=1;i<=chapters;i++)
              ^
              |
```

Comment: You only need to add "std::" before things if you don't use "using namespace std;" at the top, right? Are there any benefits to doing it this way?

Comment: @JohnLongsocks _"Are there any benefits to doing it this way?"_ Yes, you avoid clashing with functions or classes defined in `namespace  std`, with your own stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(line == "Chapter "+j){
```

`"Chapter "` is a string literal, not `std::string`, so `"Chapter "+j` adds `j` to a `const char*` pointer pointing to `"Chapter "`. For example if `j == 1`, the result of addition is `"hapter "`. You should convert it to `std::string` explicitly, as well as `j`:

```
if (line == std::string("Chapter ") + std::to_string(j)) {
```

In C++14 you can use `std::string` literals:

```
if (line == "Chapter "s + std::to_string(j)) {
```